# How can I import / export of form definitons between servers?

Tags: orbeon

I wish to develop some forms on a dev server then export the form definition and put them in a test server involving other people. Is there an import/export function for the form definitions or I need to manually move the content of the database?

Answer (score 1):

You can:

- Since 4.4, use the home page remote operations to publish forms to another server; for more on this, one the [documentation on the Form Runner home page](http://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/feature/home-page.html), look for the section about *Remote server operations*.
- Move the form definition at the database level.
- Develop your own tools that do this calling the persistence API.

If you're on 4.4, the first option is most likely your best choice. And if you want the maximum level of programmability and automation, the second or third option are the best choice.

Comment: the above mentioned link is not avillable anymore. Could you tell me where I can find the documentation

Comment: @Thirumal Thank you for the note; indeed the location for the documentation changed, and I updated my answer to point to the correct location.